# Paper Trail shows a 'create' event but no matching 'destroy'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, paper-trail-gem

I'm using PaperTrail to try and find the history of a particular instance of the Book model:

```
irb(main):025:0> PaperTrail::Version.where(item_type: "Book", item_id:     "7401738")
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<PaperTrail::Version id: 9228142, item_type:   "Book", item_id: 7401738, event: "create", whodunnit: "1156", object: nil, created_at: "2014-08-25 16:51:55">]>
```

From this, I see a create event on the instance but no other events.

Yet, it no longer exist:

```
irb(main):023:0> Book.find(7401738)
=> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Book with id=7401738
```

So, what am I missing? How did my instance disappear without a record being created in PaperTrail?

Comment: Do you have associations?

Comment: Could you please post your book model as well?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things that can prevent [PaperTrail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) from tracking the destroy event. For example, if you only specified certain events in the model. The default behavior of `has_paper_trail` is to track update, create, and destroy.
Bad:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_paper_trail :on => [:update, :create]
end
```

Good:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_paper_trail # OR :on => [:destroy]
end
```

Additionally, if you have associations in your book model and the book was deleted through those associations, PaperTrail could be having trouble. For more information, check out their [associations section](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail#associations).

Comment: Thank you @jkeuhlen. The model just declares: has_paper_trail, without specifying any particular events, so - I assume it's using the default set that includes destroy. In any case, I do have versions with destroy events, but not for all Books. Also - on first scan, there are no associations through which Books are destroyed.

Comment: @Yoram Could you edit your question to add in your model and controller for books? Those are the only two things that I can think of that can prevent PaperTrail from versioning an object. Have you tried to `reify` the book you have a version for to see what happpens? If you play around in IRB a fair amount, you could have deleted the book there which would not trigger a version.